# Fitting imageButtons into different screen sizes

Tags: android, xml, layout, scale, imagebutton

i am new to android programming.
I have a problem scaling ImageButtons to different screen-resolutions.
I made different image sizes based on the dpi and put them into hdpi(120px*72px,160dpi), mdpi(80px*48px,160dpi) and xhdpi(160px*96px,160dpi)
But on screen-resolutions like 1280x720 there is a little bit of space on the right side.
I tried things like:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

but nothing worked. Also, i am not quite sure what these do.
Like i said, i am new to android.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dmtcn4lxyxxh5wt/vpq9pBMOSl

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonsearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButtonshare"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_search"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post a screenshot and clarify the 'space' you have.

Comment: Please click on the dropbox link.

Comment: By the way this screenshot is from a Nexus 4 Emulator.

Comment: if you have 2 buttons use 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use linearlayout and than set all imagebutton's layout_weight attr to 0.25
Linearlayout must be in the parent bottom.

Like this;

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any different between dp and dip?

Comment: 0.25 because we have 4 buttons right? On the next page I'm going to have 2 buttons should I use there 0.5?

Comment: dp equals to dip and if you have 2 buttons than you should use 0.5

Comment: Okay I understand. Thank you very much. Going to try this.

Comment: I did it but it looks weird. The space on the left is now between the buttons.

Comment: You should change your linearlayout background color to black

Comment: I had a new idea. I make the ImageButton only with the Symbol and make this gray bar for mdpi hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi and put it at the bottom so the symbols dont scale and look weird. What do you think about this?

Comment: Yes, it is probably look like great. Icons on the gray bar.

Answer (score 0):

Set your layout_width attribute to "fill_parent" and make sure that the scaleType is fitXY

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Use equal weight attribute in our ImageButtons. It will occupy the space as compare to Screen Sizes, and use dp not dip.

Comment: So your answer is similar to nurisezgin?

Comment: Yeah I agree with him, but I suggest you to use dp instead of dip.